# File System Out of Resource in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, file-io

I am playing song through my app using  this piece of code,

```
private void playSong(final String song_Name) {
        try {

    p = Manager.createPlayer(Utils.getInstance().getStorageLocation()+song_Name);
            System.out.println("this line executes here 1");
            p.addPlayerListener(NewPlayerScreen.this);
            p.prefetch();
            p.realize();
            p.start();
            time = p.getDuration();
            progressTime = (int) (time/1000);
            seconds =  (int) (progressTime / 1000) % 60 ;
            minutes =  (int) ((progressTime / (1000*60)) % 60);
            _lblTime.setText(" 00:00 "+"/"+minutes+":"+seconds);
            progressBar=new GaugeField(null,0,progressTime,0,GaugeField.NO_TEXT|GaugeField.FIELD_HCENTER){
                protected void layout(int width,int height){
                   setExtent(Display.getWidth()*2/3,20);
                }
            };
            progressBar.setMargin(20, PADDING, 20, PADDING);
            timer=new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new RemindTask(),1000,1000);         
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in Play song "+e);

            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Dialog.alert("Error");  
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

This code is working fine and i am able to play songs saved on Sd card.while pressing on next song button included in my app. I am calling this method again. It plays well and sudden gives file system out of resource. As, I have debug songs are placed properly on sd card and the path given in create player method is also accurate.
please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: You don't show us what `RemindTask` is.  It looks to me like every time you play the sound, you're creating a new timer and task that runs forever.

Comment: when you click next button, close the player, then reallocate and again start the player.